# Configuring Enlightened Sound Daemon

Tags: usb, audio

I have a single audio source specified in ALSA as plughw:1,0 (a USB microphone) and I'd like several other processes to be able to access the source simultaneously.

For various reasons, each process must see the source as some kind of device, and not as stdin. The process can accept `esd` as an input device.

I've been doing some research and the documentation on `esd` is about applying several sources into one output, I guess I'm looking for the reverse.

Is this possible, and if so, is there a reference on setting it up?

/YR